# URL host comparison

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

Here I am trying to compare the hosts of 2 URLs. Even though that hosts are the same it does not respond why!

Code:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/"?ref=logo" ];
    NSURL *domain=[ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com" ];

    if ( [url host]==[domain host] ) {

        NSLog(@"hosts are matched");
    }else {
        NSLog(@"hosts are not matched!");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use  `isEqualToString:`

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/?ref=logo" ];
NSURL *domain=[ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com" ];

if ( [[url host] isEqualToString: [domain host]] ) {
    NSLog(@"hosts are matched");
}else {
    NSLog(@"hosts are not matched!");
}
```

Result

> 2011-11-23 11:55:06.182 TestApp[14404:207] hosts are matched

Comment: Indeed. Doing an == compairs will check if the two objects are physically the same in your computer's memory space. In this case, the strings are semantically the same, but stored on difference places and hence == will return false. "aString isEqualToString: anotherString] will make a character-based comparison, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Warkst, thanks. I'm going to explain this, but you were quicker ;)