# NSURLSession didReceiveChallenge multiple certificates

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlsession

How can I specify multiple certificates, depending on the server ?
In the `session:didReceiveChallenge` method I can return a NSURLCredential, but I didn't find a way to identify which URL the challenge came from.

I want do do something like this:

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential * _Nullable))completionHandler
{

  // get the certificate depending on the url
  NSString *certificatePath;
  if ([url isEqualToString: @"server1.com"]) {
      certificatePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/server1.p12"];
  } else if ([url isEqualToString: @"server2.com"]) {
      certificatePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/server2.p12"];
  }

  //... some certificate stuff

  NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity certificates:(__bridge NSArray*)certsArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
  completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
}
```

Comment: `if (url === @"server1.com")`, you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8239274/url-host-comparison ?

Comment: yes, that's just an example

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer, you can get the host of the `NSURLAuthenticationChallenge` like this:

```
NSString* host = challenge.protectionSpace.host;
```

That's it